# using gsrc to compile glibc results segment fault

Tags: linux, compilation, debian, gnu, glibc

I'm using gsrc to compile glibc in order to use multiple versions of it on my machine. I'm using debian and when I tried make -C pkg/gnu/libc install -j8 it just reports this error:

`Segmentation fault  make: *** [sysinstall-install] Error 1`

Does anyone have ideas on what this could be?

Comment: or any other ways to compile multiple versions of glibc possible.. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm using debian and when I tried `make -C pkg/gnu/libc install -j8` it just reports this error

You didn't tell how this libc has been configured. In any case, incorrectly installing GLIBC on a system is a very easy way to render your system un-bootable. This is *not* recommended for novices (and you appear to be a novice).

> compile glibc in order to use multiple versions of it on my machine

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617) on how that can be achieved.